# Retrieve video id from facebook video url

Tags: php, regex

I wan't to get the facebook video id from urls. I noticed video urls in multiple formats.

`https://www.facebook.com/username/videos/vb.100000724987616/709948045706022/?type=2&theater`

`https://www.facebook.com/username/videos/426337427566302/?theater`

`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=426337427566302&type=2&theater`

Can anyone share a regex to retrieve the id from above urls ?

Comment: there are many regex testers, easy to find with google. did you even try it on your own? please show your code.

Comment: Sorry to mention i need this for php. I'm not so good in regex and if i try to extract the segment which has digits, there is case like username too will be id.

Comment: @RobinCSamuel, try http://www.phpliveregex.com/, good for regex with a cheat sheet at the bottom

Comment: It is so easy. `'~videos/(\d+)~'`, `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a url like this: `https://www.facebook.com/username/videos/10154470513168574`

You can use `/(\d+)\/?$/` pattern - one ore more digits `\d+` followed by optional slash `\/?` at the end of line `$`.

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/vO5kH4/1).

Comment: I'm using `/videos\/(\d+)+|v=(\d+)|vb.\d+\/(\d+)/` as you and @stribizhev suggested! Thank you so much.

Comment: Funny. This doesn't work for any of the urls provide. @RobinCSamuel's comment works great, it should be the answer.

Comment: @Jake the reason for it not to work with *current* urls in the question - is the fact that question was modified after the answer posting. You can see question history.

Comment: I should have looked at the history. Of course that is the case.

Comment: @jake I posted the question and later updated. derived the new expression from Andy's answer :)